# How to remove an object from an array using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have tried a lot of things but can't seem to get any of them to work as intended. Let's say I had something like the following.

```
{
      _id: '12345',
      name: 'John Smith',
      job: [
        {
             title: 'Web Developer',
             years: '12',
             status: 'not active',
         },
         {
             title: 'supervisor',
             years: '15',
             status: 'terminated',
         },
         {
             title: 'lead developer',
             years: '3',
             status: 'not active',
         },
         {
             title: 'Software Engineer',
             years: '9',
             status: 'active',
         },
      ]
 }
```

How can I remove the object with the status of 'terminated'? Also, would it be the same to remove all objects with that status of 'not active'?

Thanks.

Comment: None of the following work. I am using **Mongoose**.

Answer (score 2):

You can use findOneAndUpdate with the $pull command.

Example:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({/* filter */}, { $pull: {array: {/* condition */}} });
```

More information:

- [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)

Answer (score 0):

Wondering if the below would work as well....

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate({'job.status' : "terminated"}, { $pull: job.$ }, {$multi : true});
```

Comment: you will have to give people the exact error that you are getting, so somebody can help.

Answer (score 0):

Remove nested document using the [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#remove-items-from-an-array-of-documents) operator

```
var query = {
    _id: "12345"
};

var update = {
    $pull: {
        job: {
            status: {
                $in: ['terminated', 'not active']
            }
        }
    }
};

db.collection.update(query, update);
```

Comment: [It works](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-update)

Comment: @j15 What is the exact code you tried, and what error are you getting in the console, please update the question

Comment: I figured it out, jsut had to make a simple change.,